# How change actionbar title on appcompat v7 library

Tags: android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I Want to Change Actionbar title to any text programically.
I use appcompat v7
Here is my code:

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View actionBarview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);

    ActionBar actioBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actioBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actioBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actioBar.setCustomView(actionBarview, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    final DrawerLayout drowerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
```

I tried: actioBar.setTitle("MyText");

But nothing happened.

Here is my custom actionbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#bfbfbf"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="......"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="menu" />
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are setting a custom view on you action bar setting title setTitle() wont work, instead you will either have to drop custom and stick with the default actionbar view or there have to be a TextView in your custom that you can get a reference and set its text to whatever your title is.

If setting customView is required for your case here is how you will have to go about it...

```
View actionBarview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
TextView tvTitle = (TextView) actionBarview.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)
tvTitle.setText(<your title here>)
```

remember `tv_title` should be in your custom view xml as a `TextView` widget. later in code you can reference to `tvTitle` for changing you actionbar Title

Comment: thank you, i updated the question and added xml codes. i set the textview id to txtBName is this what you mean?

Comment: anytime bro, just make sure to follow Google standard while using custom views for actionBar, also adopt a practise of using Toolbars instead of actionBar as its the latest replacement for actionBar